# Custom build of opentelemetry-collector is missing operator used by receiver

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I use `OpenTelemetry Collector Builder (ocb)` with this config for receivers:

```
receivers:
  - gomod: github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/receiver/tcplogreceiver v0.84.0
```

I use `syslog_parser` operator in the collector config for `tcplog` receiver:

```
  tcplog:
    listen_address: 0.0.0.0:12345
    operators:
    - id: syslogparser
      protocol: rfc3164
      type: syslog_parser
```

I'm able to build collector with ocb and Golang 1.21 succesfully, but my collector is not able to start. It produces error:

```
023/09/02 00:11:35 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'receivers': error reading configuration for "tcplog": 1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'operators[0]': unsupported type 'syslog_parser'
```

How to include `syslog_parser` operator into my custom collector ocb build, please?

I tried to use `replaces`:

```
replaces:
  - github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza => github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza v0.84.0
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

There is bug, where some operators are not registered/loaded: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/issues/26452

Workaround is to use fixed version until it is fixed in the upstream:

```
replaces:
  - github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza v0.84.0 => github.com/jangaraj/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/pkg/stanza v0.84.1
```